# First Common Lisp vector math code

Tags: performance, functional-programming, common-lisp, computational-geometry

I'm studying Common Lisp on my own. Coming from C++, Common Lisp feels kind of strange sometimes. I'd like to get some feedback on what I understood so far.

For learning purposes, I wrote this simple vector class package. The only requirements apart from correctness are non-destructiveness and performance. I want it to be as fast as possible. Is this the way to do it? Are there any serious flaws?

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage math
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :vector3
       :create-vector3
       :vector3-x
       :vector3-y
       :vector3-z
       :neg
       :mul
       :div
       :add
       :sub
       :dot
       :len
       :norm))
(in-package :math)

(defclass vector3 ()
  ((x :accessor vector3-x
      :initarg :x
      :initform 0
      :type double-float)
   (y :accessor vector3-y
      :initarg :y
      :initform 0
      :type double-float)
   (z :accessor vector3-z
      :initarg :z
      :initform 0
      :type double-float)))

(defun create-vector3 (x y z)
  (make-instance 'vector3 :x x :y y :z z))

(defmethod neg ((v vector3))
  (create-vector3 (- (vector3-x v))
          (- (vector3-y v))
          (- (vector3-z v))))

(defmethod mul ((s double-float) (v vector3))
  (create-vector3 (* s (vector3-x v))
          (* s (vector3-y v))
          (* s (vector3-z v))))

(defmethod div ((v vector3) (s double-float))
  (create-vector3 (/ (vector3-x v) s)
          (/ (vector3-y v) s)
          (/ (vector3-z v) s)))

(defmethod add ((a vector3) (b vector3))
  (create-vector3 (+ (vector3-x a) (vector3-x b))
          (+ (vector3-y a) (vector3-y b))
          (+ (vector3-z a) (vector3-z b))))

(defmethod sub ((a vector3) (b vector3))
  (create-vector3 (- (vector3-x a) (vector3-x b))
          (- (vector3-y a) (vector3-y b))
          (- (vector3-z a) (vector3-z b))))

(defmethod dot ((a vector3) (b vector3))
  (+ (* (vector3-x a) (vector3-x b))
     (* (vector3-y a) (vector3-y b))
     (* (vector3-z a) (vector3-z b))))

(defmethod len ((v vector3))
  (sqrt (+ (* (vector3-x v) (vector3-x v))
       (* (vector3-y v) (vector3-y v))
       (* (vector3-z v) (vector3-z v)))))

(defmethod norm ((v vector3))
  (let ((l (len v)))
    (if (> l 0)
    (let ((inv (/ 1.0 l)))
      (create-vector3 (* (vector3-x v) inv)
              (* (vector3-y v) inv)
              (* (vector3-z v) inv)))
    (create-vector3 (vector3-x v)
            (vector3-y v)
            (vector3-z v)))))
```

Comment: Start with using the time macro, check out how to disassemble functions, and try to find a good profiler for your lisp implementation

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few minor suggestions:

1. Use uninterned symbols instead of keywords in `defpackage` (e.g., `#:neg` instead of `:neg`) to avoid polluting the keyword package.
2. Fix your indentation.
3. Add a `defgeneric` with docs for each defmethod (you can fold `defmethod` inside `defgeneric`)
4. Decide if your objects are read-only; if they are, replace `:accessor` with `:reader`, if they are not, add mutator functions (e.g., scale in-place)
5. Rename `norm` to `normalize` (`norm` in math refers to the length of the vector)
6. Use `(plusp x)` instead of `(> x 0)`
7. Use `(/ x)` instead of `(/ 1 x)`
8. In the `else` clause in `norm` can just return the argument or `(create-vector3 0 0 0)` for clarity